# Nonparametric multiplecomparison tests for discrete data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

Suppose I have $K$ populations each consisting of $n_i$ ($i=1\dots K$) observations $x_{j,i}$ ($j=1 \dots n_i$). Each observation is comming from a Bernoulli distributed random variable $X_{j,i} \sim Bern(p_i)$. 
I would like to test the hypothesis

$H_0: p_1= \dots p_K$

against

$H_1:$ "not all $p_i$'s are equal".

For each $i$ I also want to run through all the $j \neq i$ to test if $p_i=p_j$.

I read about the Kruskal Wallis test, which seems to be kind of what I need except that it requires the data to come from a continuous distribution. 
Does anybody know what tests I can use in this case? I would be very greatful if you could explain how I should use the test as well.

Kind regards,

Comment: I don't see how a Kruskal-Wallis test is appropriate for the kind of data you describe. See my Answer on how to use a chi-squared test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is a chi-squared test for homogeneity for the $K$ populations.
For each of the $K$ samples you need the number of Successes and Failures out
of $n_i$ trials, $i = 1, \dots, K$.

**Data.** Here is data simulated in R for $K = 5$ with most $p_i$'s different.

```
set.seed(901)
x1 = rbinom(1, 100, .4);  x2 = rbinom(1, 150, .5)
x3 = rbinom(1, 110, .6);  x4 = rbinom(1, 120, .6)
x5 = rbinom(1, 150, .7);  succ = c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
fail = c(100,150,110,120,150) - succ
DTA = rbind(succ, fail); DTA

DTA = rbind(succ, fail); DTA
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
succ   37   76   67   64   99
fail   63   74   43   56   51
```

**Main chi-squared test.** A chi-squared test of homogeneity strongly rejects the null hypothesis that
all five $p_i$s are equal with P-value $0.0001 < 0.05.$

```
chisq.test(DTA)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 23.121, df = 4, p-value = 0.0001198
```

**Additional information.** You can use `$`-notation to look at observed counts (echoing the data), expected counts (based on the null hypothesis), and Pearson residuals
(their squares are 'contributions to chi-squared', which add up to
the chi-squared statistic 23.121).

- You should check observed counts
  to make sure data were correctly entered into the procedure,
- Expected
  counts to make sure they are all above 3 and mostly above 5, so that
  the chi-squared statistic will have approximately a chi-squared distribution
  with 4 degrees of freedom.
- A look at Pearson residuals with absolute
  values above 2 (especially 3) will help to find possibly interesting discrepancies between observed
  and expected counts.

See related output from R below:

```
 chisq.test(DTA)$obs
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 succ   37   76   67   64   99
 fail   63   74   43   56   51

 chisq.test(DTA)$exp
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
 succ 54.44444 81.66667 59.88889 65.33333 81.66667
 fail 45.55556 68.33333 50.11111 54.66667 68.33333

 chisq.test(DTA)$res
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
 succ -2.364179 -0.6270544  0.9188917 -0.1649572  1.918049
 fail  2.584559  0.6855062 -1.0045474  0.1803339 -2.096842
```

***Ad-hoc* tests.** Because $H_0$ was rejected, it is appropriate to make 'pairwise comparisons'
between $p_i$s. Here it is reasonable to compare $p_1$ and $p_5$. This
can be done using bracket notation `[]` to select the two relevant columns
of `DTA`.

```
chisq.test(DTA[,c(1,5)])$p.val
[1] 1.18377e-05
```

**Bonferroni criterion.** Using the Bonferroni method to prevent 'false discovery' you should declare
such an *ad hoc* comparison as significant only if the P-value is below
$0.05/m$ where $m$ is the number of comparisons performed. The *ad hoc* comparison of $p_1$ with $p_5$ is significant by this criterion.

By contrast, we do not find a significant difference between $p_3$ and $p_4.$

```
chisq.test(DTA[,c(3,4)])$p.val
[1] 0.3049811
```

Comment: Great reply, thanks!